# IDE - Divergencia entre IDEs em relacao ao tab [ao Enter]

Tags: eclipse, codificação-de-caracteres, ide, sublime-text

Por motivos de `hadware`, sou o único em minha equipe que esta utilizando Sublime Text 3, os demais estão utilizando Eclipse Luna ou Mars, ate ai nada de mais.

Contudo desde a troca tenho tido alguns problemas na parte do `commit`,
pois meus aquivos começaram ficar com divergências em varias linhas, e quando vou verificar o que é, se trata apenas do espaçamento `tab`.

Já verifiquei a questão do `tab-size`, ambos esta com 4, e o `encoding` ambos estão com `UTF-8`.

Haveria mais alguma configuração que poderia causar esta divergência?

Penso que se fosse o caso de `encode` não deveria causar erro no espaçamento do aquivo inteiro em vez do apenas alguns fragmentos?

#### Edição

Estava verificando novamente os commits foi então que achei a opção, `ShowWhiteSpace Characters` no eclipse.

E na linha em que estão ocorrendo os erros tem esta peculiaridade :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver no final da linha há **`¤`**, alguém sabe disser que caractere é este? e para que serve? ele é setado quando dou `enter` no eclipse.

Comment: Confirme se o Eclipse está convertendo espaços para tabs ou se é o sublime que está fazendo isso.

Comment: Prefira usar sempre espaços ao invés de `\t`, evita esse tipo de problema.

Comment: Todo mundo ai usa o mesmo S.O?

Comment: @LuisHenrique discordo, o que tem q ser feito é um alinhamento do padrão, independente de qual ele seja, eclipse por exemplo usa por padrão tabulação, já o sublime usa por padrão espaços, portanto, no lugar de todos os que usam tabulação mudarem pra espaço seria interessante configurar o sublime para usar tabulação, já que ele é o único a usar sublime.

Comment: @gmsantos no Eclipse `Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors` a opcão `insert space for tabs` esta desmarcada, e em `Preferences->PHP->Code Style->Formatter` estou usando `PHP convention` na qual `tab policity` = `Tab`. No sublime `translate_tabs_to_spaces` = `false`.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert não utilizo nenhum dos dois, só comentei conceitualmente qual pode ser o problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa divergência ocorre nos trechos que você edita do arquivo no 
`Sublime`
?

No `eclipse` há uma configuração para remover o esse `whiteSpace`. Você indo em `Preference -> [linguagem, por exemplo JAVA] -> Editor -> Save Action`, marque o check `Perform the selected actions on save`, depois `Additional actions`. Em seguida clique em `Configure...` e na aba `Code Organizing` marque a opção `Remove trailing whitespace`.

Além disso você pode configurar para exibir esses caracteres. Basta ir em `Preference -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors` e na opção `Show whitespace character` (deve ser marcada) tem um link `configure visibility`. Clicando irá abrir uma tela para você marcar os caracteres que deseja visualizar em diferentes posições no código. Para o `space` (ou qualquer outro que quiser) marque a opção `trailing`. Reinicie o eclipse e verifique se o problema continua acontecendo.

Comment: Através de sua resposta achei o problema, vendo o símbolo que o eclipse usa para `\r`, que seria justamente o de minha "edição na pergunta", na qual eu conhecia como LF, desta forma vi que o único problema é a divergência entre Linux e Windows, na qual Linux usa apenas CR (`\n`) e o Windows LF CR (`\r\n`).

Answer (score 3):

Você pode configurar o seu editor para utilizar o padrão de tabulações, as opções padrão usadas pelo editor acessando o menu `Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings - Default`. Todas estas opções podem ser personalizadas através do menu `Settings - User`.

```
{"translate_tabs_to_spaces": false}: converte espaços em tab.
```

Comment: a configuracao default ja esta deste modo, mas obrigado e ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Basta vocês usarem: http://editorconfig.org/

simplesmente configura um arquivo `.editorconfig` na raiz do seu projeto, instale o plugin para a sua respectiva IDE e pronto! todos terão a mesma configuração.

Comment: Agradeço a recomendação, irei sugerir ao resto da equipe.